# Pandas : Get the least number of records so all columns have at least one non null value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 62 columns that are largely null. Some records have multiple columns with non-null values, others just a single non-null. I'm wondering if there's a way to use .dropna or other strategy **to return the least number of rows with each column having at least one non-null value.**

For a simplified example

```
       a          b         c
      NaN        1         NaN
      1          NaN       NaN
      NaN        NaN       NaN
      NaN        1         1
```

Would return

```
      a          b         c
      1          NaN       NaN
      NaN        1         1
```

...

Comment: shouldn't the first row also pass the cut?

Comment: I don't believe that question answers what I'm trying to do here as I'm not trying to drop rows with nulls in very column. The first row would not be returned as row 4 has two non-nulls in column b and c. Since it has better 'coverage' that way the least number of rows with at least one non-null in each column would be row 2 and row 4

Comment: That's a pretty complex problem you got there. If I may ask, what is the application? Genomics? Maybe we can modify the problem so it is a little easier, because as is you are looking for an optimal solution and even a non-optimal solution is still pretty hard to find.

Comment: It's actually for creating a subset of a dataset to test an application on. Looking to test a variety of data with the least number of tests possible.

Comment: Aite, can you provide a copy-and-pasteable example, please? you can use `df.to_dict()` to provide code (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame({your:values, go:here})`) we can use for your example.

Comment: The problem as stated is NP hard: it's a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple greedy solution that should do the job but won't guarantee you have the lowest number of rows (as @chthonicdaemon said the problem is NP-hard)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan],'b':[1, np.nan, np.nan, 1],'c':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1]})
df_orig = df
cols = df.columns.tolist()

rows = []
while not df.empty:
    ## Find the row with most non-null column entries
    x = df.notnull().sum(axis=1).idxmax() # edit - fix for null/nonnull
    ## Add the row to our list and continue
    rows.append(x)
    ## Remove the columns from our dataframe
    df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.loc[[x]].notnull().any()].tolist())

## Access the dataframe with only 'essential' rows
df_orig.loc[rows]
```

Out:

```
    a   b   c
3   NaN 1.0 1.0
1   1.0 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Right now you're assuming all non-null values are 1.  I think you want something like `df.notnull().sum(axis=1).idxmax()`.

Comment: This worked for what I was looking to do. Thanks Brendan.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function doing a huge filtering of `NaN`, but it doesn't guarantee the minimum number of rows either. In fact, [Brendan Frick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927450/2504700) has always returned less rows. This one is more performance oriented.

The idea is basically to count the number of not-null values, and slice the dataframe imposing that a count threshold. If the sliced dataframe fulfills the condition of at least one non-null value, it is return, otherwise, the threshold is modified.

```
def custom_dropna(df):
    counts=df.count(axis=1)
    for i in sorted(set(counts.values),reverse=True):
        dropped_df = df[counts>=i]
        if dropped_df.count().min()>=1:
            return dropped_df
```

### Performance analysis

To check whether the function worked and how it performed, I generated a random input dataframe, and executed the functions for different properties of the df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1],size=(500,62),p=[.2,.8]),columns=range(62))
```

#### P(null)=0.2, rows=500

```
custom_dropna(df).count().values
# returned a dataframe with 3 rows
# [3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3
# 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 3]
# 631 µs ± 9.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
answer_Brendan_Frick(df).count().values
# returned 2 rows
# [1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
# 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1]
# 3 ms ± 8.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I repeated the timeit and code execution around 5 times. `custom_dropna` returned between 2 and 5 rows, whereas `answer_Brendan_Frick` returned 2 always. The execution times were basically the same each repetition, .6-.7 ms and 2.9-3.1 ms respectively.

#### P(null)=0.8, rows=500

```
custom_dropna(df).count().values
# returned 12 rows
# [2 4 5 4 4 3 5 3 4 3 2 8 6 5 4 2 5 4 6 8 6 2 5 5 6 4 3 1 4 4 4 4 6 7 4 3 4
# 5 3 4 3 1 4 3 1 6 3 2 6 6 4 4 4 5 5 5 3 4 4 6 5 4]
# 1.96 ms ± 34.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
answer_Brendan_Frick(df).count().values
# returned 6 rows
# [1 2 2 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 1 2
# 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2]
# 8.21 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I repeated the timeit and code execution around 5 times. `custom_dropna` returned between 7 and 13 rows, whereas `answer_Brendan_Frick` returned 6 always. The execution times were basically the same each repetition, 1.5-2 ms and 8.1-8.3 ms respectively.

#### P(null)=0.8, rows=5000

In this case, `custom_dropna` returned between 7 and 23 rows, whereas `answer_Brendan_Frick` returned 5 always. The execution times were basically the same each repetition, 2.4-2.7 ms and 14.3-14.5 ms respectively.

The large number of rows returned by `custom_dropna` is due to many rows having the same value of counts, which will become worse for large dataframes.